# How to read from a text (.txt) file and place data into an excel 2016 document using VBA Macros editor?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to read the following text document (see first picture):[image: Text document image]

and place data into an excel document in the pictured manner (see second image):
[image: Excel document image]

I want to do this with an Excel VBA macros but I do not have the slightest idea on how to do so. I am very new to excel VBA and I do not have the slightest idea on where to begin.

Comment: So the delimiter is [Space] or multiple [Space]s?

Answer (score 1):

Use following sub.

```
Sub txtImport()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\HARUN\Documents\Test.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "Test"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will do that without looping and regardless of number of spaces between the columns.

```
Sub Test()

 Dim Fn As String, WS As Worksheet, st As String

 Fn = "D:\tttt\test.txt" ' the file path and name
 Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")

 'Read text file to st string
 With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not .FileExists(Fn) Then
        MsgBox Fn & "  : is missing."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If FileLen(Fn) = 0 Then
            MsgBox Fn & "  : is empty"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            With .OpenTextFile(Fn, 1)
             st = .ReadAll
             .Close
            End With
        End If
    End If
 End With

 'Replace every one or more space in st string with vbTab
 With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  .Pattern = "[ ]+"
  .Global = True
  .Execute st
  st = .Replace(st, vbTab)
 End With

 'Put st string in Clipboard
 With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    .SetText st
    .PutInClipboard
 End With

 'Paste Clipboard to range
 WS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have csv file (like you have shown, just difference is in delimiters), then the code should be:

```
Sub ReadData()
Dim line, array() As String
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rfile = FSO.OpenTextFile(*your full path to the file*, 1) 'connection for reading

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do Until rfile.AtEndOfStream
    line = rfile.ReadLine
    array = Split(line, ",") 'I assumed that delimiter is comma
    For j = 0 To UBound(array)
        Cells(i, j + 1).Value = array(j)
    Next j 
    i = i + 1
Loop

rfile.Close

End Sub
```